# How can I repeat the line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, repeat, lines

How can I repeat the line in notepad++ ?

For example I have the following input:

```
a 01
a 02
a 03
a 04
```

And I would like it to become:

```
a 01
a 01
a 02
a 02
a 03
a 03
a 04
a 04
```

So every line should be displayed **twice**.

Comment: While this isn't worthy of an answer, I'd like to point out that notepad++ supports user-created arbitrary plugin creation. http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html. Have you considered writing one?

Comment: Good idea @user834688 - a "zip" plugin would be quite simple to make.

Answer (score 43):

Open the search dialog box and write :-

Find:

`^.*$`

Replace:

`$0\n$0`

Comment: Make sure to enable regex search in the search dialog and consolidate your linefeeds afterwards (`\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`).

Answer (score 42):

If you don't mind the semi-manual process, you can start at the first line and repeat the following key combination until you reach the end of the document (you get very fast at this)

<kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd>

This duplicates the current line, then moves down twice (to the line following the newly duplicated one).

If you have a large document, you can record this once as a macro (see the Macro menu), then use either <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> (Playback) repeatedly -- you can just hold those keys down.  Or use the Macro option **"Run a Macro Multiple Times..."**

Comment: Technically, you could shorten this procedure by working bottom-up, i.e. duplicate line, move up, duplicate, up, etc. :-) But, as you said, if it's repetitive enough to be annoying, a macro might be worth it.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the mouse cursor on the line you want to repeat, then you can use `Ctrl-D` shortcut to duplicate the line. Or you can use the same shortcut selecting multiple lines.

Comment: Regarding your comment *"Or you can use the same shortcut selecting multiple lines."*... This does not interleave duplicates.  Instead, it treats the entire block as one "line" and creates a duplicate copy following the block.

Answer (score 5):

Highlight the desired code and press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.
Don't highlight if you want to duplicate just the current line.

Comment: simplest answer here

Answer (score 1):

To repeat each line with RegEx in NotePad++, press <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd> ; Then:

> Find what : `^(.*)$`
>
> Replace with : `$1\n$1`

> **Note:** Select **Regular expression** in Search Mode and **Uncheck ".
> matches newline"**

---

To repeat each line manually, select the line and press <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> on your keyboard.

> **Note:** To selecting the whole texts of desired line, click on the line
> three times (mouse triad-click).

Comment: No needs to select the whole line for duplication. Moreover same answer was already given many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using windows**, I recommend writing an auto-hotkey (AHK) script to do this for you. This way, your special text-manipulation script will work in **any IDE**, not just notepad++. All you would have to do is copy your text example to the clipboard, and then execute an AHK script that reads data from the clipboard using the %clipboard% variable. Then you can load the clipboard with the results of your script and send a CTRL+V signal.