# How can I duplicate the current line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to click a keyboard shortcut and that will duplicate the line that the cursor is currently in, ie. it will paste the same line just below. Is that possible? It is in EmEditor, but I need to do it in Notepad++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repeat the line in notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538828/how-can-i-repeat-the-line-in-notepad)

Comment: CTRL+D does exactly this

Answer (score 7):

Use `Ctrl-D` (more shortcuts [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew First: I didn't notice the duplicate comment. Seconed:  now that I look into it I see it's not exactly the same question. Third: what's the big deal?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks for your input